# How to override magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html in custom module

Tags: magento2, module, cart, custom, quote

I have custom additional options in quote and want to hide few options in the mini cart.

How to skip a specific index in Knockout js array from the following code

```
 <dl class="product options list">
                    <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                    <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                    <dd class="values">
                        <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                            <span data-bind="html: option.value.join('<br>')"></span>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        <!-- ko if: (!Array.isArray(option.value) && option.option_type == 'file') -->
                            <span data-bind="html: option.value"></span>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        <!-- ko if: (!Array.isArray(option.value) && option.option_type != 'file') -->
                            <span data-bind="text: option.value"></span>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </dd>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </dl>
```

Comment: Bro if you are using theme then you can directly copy it with same path in theme and if you want it to override in module them i think need to use mixin for it

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps to override this HTML file in the custom module:

1. First Create a Custom module. You can follow this link to create a
   module:
   https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/
2. Now create **requirejs-config.js** file inside
   "Vendor/Module/view/frontend".
3. Add below content inside
   **Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**:

   ```
   var config = {
   map: {
       '*': {
           'Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/default.html':
               'Vendor_Module/template/minicart/item/default.html'
       }
   } };
   ```
4. Now override file at this path
   **Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html**

Comment: Thanks it worked

Comment: Glad to hear. Feel free to accept and upvote the answer if it's useful for you.